# Finding basis and rank

Tags: linear-algebra

A = [1 3 4 -1 2; 2 6 6 0 -3; 3 9 3 6 -3; 3 9 0 9 0 ]

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 3 & 4 &-1 & 2 \\
  2 & 6 & 6 & 0 &-3 \\
  3 & 9 & 3 & 6 &-3 \\
  3 & 9 & 0 & 9 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

B is A's echelon form

B = [1 3 4 -1 2; 0 0 1 -1 1; 0 0 0 0 -5; 0 0 0 0 0]

$B=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 3 & 4 &-1 & 2 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &-5 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

1. Find the bases for Col A and Row A.

For row A, would that be rows 1, 2 and 3 of B since they are non-zero. For col A, would that be columns 1, 3, and 5 of A since those are the pivot columns.

2. Determine rank A.
   3
3. Basis for nul A.
   I haven't done this yet, but the dimension should be 2 since there are 3 pivots. I would basically just set all the equations in B to zero and solve.

Can someone verify if that's correct, and if not, what should I do?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). Particularly for matrices, see also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/how-to-input-matrices-when-posting-questions-at-math-stackexchange).